# Laravel query optimization

Tags: laravel

I have a query in laravel:

```
...
$query = $model::group_by($model->table().'.'.$model::$key);
$selects = array(DB::raw($model->table().'.'.$model::$key));
...
$rows = $query->distinct()->get($selects);
```

this works fine and gives me the fields keys' that I need but the problem is that I need to get all the columns and not just the Key.

using this:

```
$selects = array(DB::raw($model->table().'.'.$model::$key), DB::raw($model->table().'.*'));
```

is not an option, cuz it's not working with PostgreSQL, so i used  `$rows`  to get the rest of columns:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($rows); $i++)
{
    $rows[$i] = $model::find($rows[$i]->key);
}
```

but as you see this is it's so inefficient, so what can i do to make it faster and more efficient?

you can find the whole code here: https://gist.github.com/neo13/5390091

ps. I whould use join but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't pass anything in to get() and it will return all the columns. Also the key is presumably unique in the table so I don't exactly understand why you need to do the group by.

```
$models = $model::group_by( $model->table() . '.'.  $model::$key )->get();
```